# error saving photo in database 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'user'

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I have a model with Usuario where the profile foto goes and it saves perfectly in the database, so to be able to add more images as if it were a gallery, I created another model called Gallery, I copied the same specificiation of what was already working in the model Usuario, however he is not saving the photos in the database, and I do not know where I am going wrong.
I appreciate any help.
and I need the Gallery model to receive the foreign Usuario key

Erro:
IntegrityError at /gallery-novo/
null value in column "usuario_id_id" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (3, IMG_20180622_101716179_BURST006.jpg, eu e meu amor, null).

views.py

```
    def gallery(request):
        gallery = Gallery.objects.all()
        form = GalleryForm()
        data = {'gallery': gallery, 'form': form}
        return render(request, 'gallery.html', data)   

    def gallery_novo(request):
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = GalleryForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
            if form.is_valid():
                form.save(user=request.user)
                return redirect('sistema_perfil')
        else:
            form = GalleryForm
        return render(request, 'gallery.html', {'form': form})
```

models.py

```
    class Gallery(models.Model):
        gallery = StdImageField( blank=False,  variations={
            'large': (600, 400),
            'thumbnail': (100, 100, True),
            'medium': (300, 200),
        })
        titulo = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False)
        usuario_id = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=False)
```

forms.py

```
             class GalleryForm(forms.ModelForm):
          gallery = forms.FileField(
                        widget=forms.ClearableFileInput(attrs={'multiple': 'True'}))
          titulo = forms.CharField()

          class Meta:
                 model = Gallery
                 fields = ( 'gallery', 'titulo')

          def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
                 self.request = kwargs.pop('request', None)
                 return super(GalleryForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)


 def save(self, commit=True, user=None):
     form = super(GalleryForm, self).save(commit=False)
     form.usario_id = user
     if commit:
        form.save()
     return form
```

gallery.html

```
    {%extends 'bases/base.html' %}
    {% load static %}
    {% load bootstrap %}
    {% load widget_tweaks %}
    {% load crispy_forms_tags %}

    {% block main %}

    <div class="card text-white bg-primary">
        <div class="card-header"><p class="card-text">
            <small class="text-muted">
                <a href="{% url 'sistema_index' %}" class="text-white ">Home /</a>  
                <a  class="text-white">Cadastro</a>

            </small></a></p> Cadastro de Usúario 
        </div>
        <div class="card title  ">
        <div class="card-body text-secondary">  
            <form class="exampleone" action="{%  url 'sistema_gallery_novo'  %}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="form" name="form" validate >
                    {% csrf_token %}

        <div class="form-row"> 
                <div class="form-group col-md-4">


            {{ form.gallery | as_crispy_field }}

        </div>
                <div class="form-group col-md-4">


            {{ form.titulo | as_crispy_field }}

        </div>

        <div class="form-group col-md-4">


        </div>

            </div>


            </div>

                        <button type="submit"  class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Cadastrar</button>

                </form>


        </div>
        </div>
        </div>



    {% endblock %}

    {% block rightcol %}
    {% include 'bases/rightcol.html' %}
    {% endblock %}

    {% block footer %}
    {% include 'bases/footer.html' %}
    {% endblock %}
```

urls.py

```
   url(r'gallery/$', gallery, name='sistema_gallery'),
   url(r'gallery-novo/$', gallery_novo, name='sistema_gallery_novo'),
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion, you are reinventing the wheel, the django right approach is to use [`commit=False` on save method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method):

```
def gallery_novo(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = GalleryForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            my_novo_gallery = form.save(commit=False)  #save no commit
            my_novo_gallery.user=request.user          #set user
            my_novo_gallery.save()                     #save to db
            return redirect('sistema_perfil')
```

Comment: Hi, my friend, perfect, your way works, but I'm not able to call the image inside the html and what I found strange is that the image also does not appear inside the django a

Comment: Glad to help you. About the images ... it is a new issue not related with this one. Just post a new question, before to post the question take a look to: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) Good luck!

Comment: I've already asked the question, I'm very new, but I'm learning fast [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55086065/i-can-not-show-the-photo-that-is-in-the-database]

Comment: Nice, don't forget to don't post irrelevant data, like all this `Usuario` properties ( `data_nascimento`, ... )

Comment: I have already removed these models, thank you friend, and if you can help me in the new doubt, thank you

Comment: No, you didn't. For example, to include `bairro = models.CharField(max_length=30)` in your question don't help at all. Don't copy-paste all your code, only relevant code to issolate the issue.